# Spatial Adjustment of Many Points in Geometric Network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, geometric-network, spatial-adjustment

I have been receiving surveyed water valve data and editing our point feature class accordingly.  The current procedure is to use the attribute transfer mapping tool and click from source layer to target layer for each surveyed point, with transfer geometry on. Instead of doing this manually I want to move all of the selected valve points from a feature class , which are connected by a geometric network, to the shapefile point which has been surveyed.

Is there any way to do this within an editing session?

I want to move the points with a geometric network connection to a new location. There is a unique field I can join the point feature class and shapefile to but I still don't know how to update the location for all the points at the same time.

Comment: Add xy coordinates to surveyed, join to original and do arcpy.Point(pointx, pointy) in field calculator on field Shape.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!! I will try this on a couple and see how it works out for me.